# List of data munging libraries

Tags: libraries, data-sets, pdb, data-management

I am trying to put together a complete list of all of the tools that computational scientists have found useful when trying to munge data, i.e. take data in one format, extract the useful bits, and put it into a different format.

So what are the libraries that you've used in the past to obtain data from fixed-width, CSV, XML, etc. files, to sort the data, and to output it into useful formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite language for these tasks is Python; Perl also works for those who are so inclined.

Python modules:

- The [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module from the Python standard library handles parses CSV files.
- The Python standard library also has modules for [standard markup languages](http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html) like XML, HTML, SGML, etc.
- For fixed-width strings, see [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848537/writing-parsing-a-fixed-width-file-using-python).
- I haven't used this module, but supposedly [p3d](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2744707/) is a Python module that will help with parsing protein data in pdb format.
- The [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module in Python can be quite useful.
- You can also Google or check the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) for other Python packages that suit your needs.

Perl modules:

- The [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module works for CSV processing. I've used it, and it's relatively intuitive.
- The [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) and [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm) modules seem like they would work for XML processing, though there are a lot of XML modules available on the [Comprehensive Perl Archive Network](http://search.cpan.org/) (CPAN), so feel free to pick one that suits your preference.
- The [HTML::Tree::Scanning](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.2/lib/HTML/Tree/Scanning.pod) modules seem to serve the same sort of purpose for HTML.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494611/how-can-i-extract-columns-from-a-fixed-width-format-in-perl) from Stack Overflow talks about extracting fixed-width data from files using Perl.
- [Regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) are baked into Perl.
- CPAN is also a good source to look for other libraries.

C++ libraries:

- There are a bunch of XML parser libraries (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c) on Stack Overflow). Particularly reputable are [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/), and the C++ bindings to [Gdome2](http://gdome2.cs.unibo.it/) (my personal favorite).
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c) from Stack Overflow talks about extracting data from CSV files.
- For other standard formats, there's a good chance there's a parser out there (HTML, etc.). A lot of times, the Perl and Python versions of parser libraries are language bindings for C or C++ parser libraries.
- For fixed-width files, you can use [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/).
- [This post](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use&ei=eHIHT7a-FqHb0QGu_42EAg&usg=AFQjCNF0B87qu8nZzPI9p6SHGhwVs5WL4w) from Stack Overflow talks about C++ regular expression libraries; also see [Boost::Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) and [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) (from C).

C libraries:

- Again, there are many XML parser libraries. Worth checking out are [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), [Gdome2](http://gdome2.cs.unibo.it/), and [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).
- A lot of people seem to roll their own C libraries for CSV parsing. I found [documentation for a library](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFwQFjAF&url=http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/c_CkCsvRef.html&ei=SnMHT5rZBOj10gHs8ICJAg&usg=AFQjCNFEuDmblEIF8lk567mMO5sNUVmMFw), but it seems a little sketchy.
- For fixed-width files, you can again use [fprintf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEAQFjAD&url=http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html&ei=u3MHT_DBBYX30gG58cXFAg&usg=AFQjCNG2QKGjWOpmVUl2yHXdGpDvVA_RZQ).
- The best C regular expression library I know of is [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Good summary, I as well prefer Python. I would add to the list the NetCDF4 module for Python. Netcdf is data format commonly used in geosciences, and besides Python, there are interfaces for this format for Fortran, C/C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1):

When the main task is changing the *shape or structure* of data rather than reading a specific file format (like .mat or hfd5 for a matrix of the same shape), then I find [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/) excellent for the task.  Its native data structure is essentially a tree (list of lists of lists ...), and it can do flexible transformations on them using pattern matching or other means.

It has two weaknesses in my opinion:

- If it doesn't already support the input/output file format, it's not the best tool to implement your own importer in (unless the format is trivial).  [Here's the listing of supported formats.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html)  ([PDB](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PDB.html) is supported.)
- It works well if all your data fits comfortably into memory.  I find that it is not a very good tool for sequential data processing (i.e. reading a small bit of the input and outputting it immediately).

For kneading complex or structured data into the desired shape (think high dimensional ragged arrays or XML-like structured data), it is a very good tool though.

Comment: I think Mathematica is a fine tool for this task if you're post-processing data (which seems to be what you're suggesting in your answer), or your entire workflow is in Mathematica. If you need to process data as an intermediate step in a language other than Mathematica, Mathematica won't be so helpful. Furthermore, Mathematica is not free unless you belong to an institution that has a site license.

Comment: @Geoff The OP did not mention that he is looking for free tools only.  I expect most readers here work in academia, so many will have access to Mathematica.  It is the tool I use most often, and I tried to describe what it is useful for and what it isn't.  It is one of my main tools for reshaping data. To be honest, I find it quite a turnoff that there is always some kind of negative feedback when one mentions a non-free tool.

Comment: I agree that the OP didn't mention he was looking for free tools only. I also agree that it's frustrating to see people hash out the free versus non-free. I think commercial tools tend to be more polished and usable than their free counterparts, and I think that outright hostility to commercial products is misplaced. Nevertheless, paying for a license is a barrier to entry for some people, and one that I think is worth acknowledging.

Comment: There's not just "free" and "non-free". The "non-free" category splits into "affordable for most scientists" and "other". A Mathematica license is of the same order of magnitude of my annual working budget, so I need a very good reason to buy one. Most commercial programs are much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

I aggree that Python is really good on this task. I would like to add some tools to the list:

- If you want to extract data from the web, or maybe fill in a form easilly, then [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is the best option.
- I heard that [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is *really really* good on parsing XML/HTML files.